# Laravel : image with base64 source ,not able to view in email

Tags: php, laravel, email, base64

I am working with laravel below is steps which I have followed,

- I am using editor for emails to user,
- from editor I have upload image,
- that image is uploaded as base64 format
- I am sending that editor content in email to user

I have checked that base64 string is correct and showing me image
also able to display that image with my system

but when I am going to send that image in email ,

that image is not visible for me.

I have checked there in image src attribute, there is showing like -

```
<img style="width:224px">
```

in gmail ,here src attribute is removed ,but I have checked that tag befor send email , there was src tag with proper base64 encoded string

Please help me to show image in email ,

To send mail I am using laravel own configuration for email as below,

```
use App\Events\SendMail;

$mailData['toName']       = $toUserFullname;
$mailData['toEmail']      = $toEmail;
$mailData['fromName']     = $fromName;
$mailData['fromEmail']    = $fromEmail;
$mailData['emailSubject'] =  $templateData['email_subject'];
$mailData['emailContent'] = $templateData['email_body'];
\Event::fire(new SendMail($mailData));
```

Comment: Can you paste the editor content here?

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoded images are not well supported in emails. They aren't supported in most web email clients (including Gmail) and are completely blocked in Outlook.

So the first solution that comes to my mind is to create actual image file from base64 string before sending email. Something like that colud help:

```
$filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg"; 
$decoded=base64_decode($base64_string_img); 
file_put_contents("path/to/save/image/".$filename_path,$decoded);
```

You also shouldn't forget to unlink this images in case you don't need them after.

You can also try using [inline attachemnts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#inline-attachments).

```
<img src="{{ $message->embedData($data, $name) }}">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,that is also option, but is there any possibility to show image in email without upload that image to our server

Comment: I'm almost sure that ther is no such option. But you can upload image, send it and then delete from your server. Link to attachment image and thats it.

Comment: I am using editor to upload image , Here if I get images from html and decode it upload to server, but how I ca replace that image souce with url in html for specific location ?